# xrandr - can't set fullscreen

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, display, xrandr, bspwm

I have two monitors. I disabled my primary monitor(eDP-1) by running this command on startup to display on secondary monitor(DP-1) only.

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --off
```

The primary monitor is disabled and everything is shown on the secondary monitor. But only about three-quarters of the secondary monitor is used and the rest of the screen is black. The windows are not positioned on the top left corner only. I can hover my mouse over the black area but my window manager only covers the top left portion as show in the image.
[image]
The display looks like this. Only the white portion is used and the rest is black.

Display information:

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1600x900      60.00 +  59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm 
panning 1920x1080+0+0
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I use bspwm on ubuntu.

Comment: Can you repro the issue under more common DEs like Gnome or KDE or even XFCE?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov everything works fine in gnome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. I finally fixed it by setting the secondary monitor as primary monitor before disabling the primary monitor by using the following command

```
xrandr --output "DP-2" --primary --above "eDP-1"
```